# Change format of created_at in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, timestamp, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am calling the date a record was created at in a basic app running Rails 3.1.

```
<%= @issue.created_at %>
```

The above outputs the following timestamp:

```
2011-09-10 14:44:24 UTC
```

What is the simplest way of altering the way this displays? I would like something like this:

```
10 Sept. 2011
```

and then somehow call it again with a different format:

```
14:44
```

so I can call it twice and merge the two together:

```
10 Sept. 2011
14:44
```

The reason I want to call it twice rather than create a helper to format a two line date/time is to allow me to call the date in some places and just the time in others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use I18n. Take a look at some example http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats. It's a clean and flexible way of formatting dates and times.

Comment: Using the example in that link I now have <%= @issue.created_at, :format => :short %>, which results in an Exception error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 77):

The simplest thing to do is to use the strftime function

```
# Day / Month / Year
@issue.created_at.strftime("%d %b. %Y")
# Hour:Min
@issue.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")
```

You could put those two calls in separate helpers if you find yourself doing it a lot.

Comment: I get a no method error if I put those into the Issues helper file. Should I be altering the way I call created_at?

Comment: Some may find this useful along with this solution: [strftime docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

Comment: @PeterPiper it depends on what you're doing, but you should also strongly consider http://stackoverflow.com/a/7372752/625365 in most cases.

Answer (score 9):

```
<%= l(@issue.created_at, :format=>:your_format) %>
```

in locale YAML (app/config/locale/country_id.yml) you must declare

```
time:
 formats:
  your_format: '%d %b. %Y'
  your_another_format: '%I:%M'
```

Date formatting should be declared inside your i18n YAML definition file for easy configure, and other date format could be found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2255)

Answer (score 7):

Check out http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/ for an easy way to customize date/time formatting @spike

Comment: Add Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" or some variation of this string it into a file in config/initializers (you could call it date_and_time.rb)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

`@issue.created_at.to_date.iso8601`

Answer (score 0):

to_s also takes format input argument:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s